# Jquery animate only working on first click

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

So I have the following basic html

```
<div id="front-page-slide">

    <div id = "slider-panel">

        Social Logins here

    <div id = "slide-now-text">
       <span id="slide-click">Sign-in using email <i class="icon-chevron-sign-up"></i></span>
    </div>

        Email login here <- this part resides outside of the #front-page-slider wrapper until the user clicks on the above span

    </div>

</div>
```

The container div #front-page-slide has a fixed width and height, with overflow hidden.

What i want to achieve is to move the inner #slider-panel up by 320px when the user clicks #slide-click.

Ive got this jquery working fine on the first click, however i can't for the life of me get it to return to its original position.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#slide-click" ).click(function() {
        jQuery( "#slider-panel" ).animate({"margin-top":"-320px"}, 1000);
        jQuery("#slide-now-text").html('<span id="slide-click-back"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-down"> Go back </i></span>');   

    });



    jQuery( "#slide-click-back" ).click(function() {
        jQuery( "#slider-panel" ).animate({"margin-top":"320px"}, 1000);
        jQuery("#slide-now-text").html('<span id="slide-click"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-down"> sign up </i></span>');    

    });
   });
```

Ive tried everything i can think of, ids, classes, conflicts you name it but ive come to the conclusion there is something fundamentally stupid in the way im trying to do it.

Any help would be great!

Comment: please add a `jsfiddle`

Comment: Guys!! please use jsfiddle to ask Jquery related question..

Comment: My apologies - http://jsfiddle.net/X48ZT/

Comment: Check this now.. http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/X48ZT/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use on click here -

```
jQuery( "html" ).on('click', '#slide-click', function() {
    jQuery( "#slider-panel" ).animate({"margin-top":"-320px"}, 1000);
    jQuery("#slide-now-text").html('<span id="slide-click-back"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-down"> Go back </i></span>');   

});

jQuery( "html" ).on('click', '#slide-click-back', function() {
    jQuery( "#slider-panel" ).animate({"margin-top":"320px"}, 1000);
    jQuery("#slide-now-text").html('<span id="slide-click"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-down"> sign up </i></span>');    

});
```

why on click ? because `#slide-click-back` is dynamically loaded when you are clicking `#slide-click` and you need to use jquery on click function if you want any event when click into dynamically loaded content.

Comment: Don't use `jQuery("html")` as this means it will capture click events for every element on the page.  Use the parent div id instead :)

Comment: Use 'live' or 'on' on dynamic added element. If you want event with dynamic element use 'live' or 'on' e.g. $('#slide-click-back').live('click', function(){//your function});

Comment: @NeerajSingh live doesn't work in latest version of jquery. Its been depreciated.